# Allocating N tonnes of food in K rooms with M capacity

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion

I found this problem online:

> You have N tonnes of food and K rooms to store them into. Every room has a capacity of M. In how many ways can you distribute the food in the rooms, so that every room has at least 1 ton of food.

My approach was to recursively find all possible variations that satisfy the conditions of the problem. I start with an array of size K, initialized to 1. Then I keep adding 1 to every element of the array and recursively check whether the new array satisfies the condition. However, the recursion tree gets too large too quickly and the program takes too long for slightly higher values of N, K and M.

What would be a more efficient algorithm to achieve this task? Are there any optimizations to be done to the existing algorithm implementation?

This is my implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    // keeping track of valid variations, disregarding duplicates
    public static HashSet<String> solutions = new HashSet<>();

    // calculating sum of each variation
    public static int sum(int[] array) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : array) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void distributionsRecursive(int food, int rooms, int roomCapacity, int[] variation, int sum) {
        // if all food has been allocated
        if (sum == food) {
            // add solution to solutions
            solutions.add(Arrays.toString(variation));
            return;
        }

        // keep adding 1 to every index in current variation
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms; i++) {
            // create new array for every recursive call
            int[] tempVariation = Arrays.copyOf(variation, variation.length);
            // if element is equal to room capacity, can't add any more in it
            if (tempVariation[i] == roomCapacity) {
                continue;
            } else {
                tempVariation[i]++;
                sum = sum(tempVariation);
                // recursively call function on new variation
                distributionsRecursive(food, rooms, roomCapacity, tempVariation, sum);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    public static int possibleDistributions(int food, int rooms, int roomCapacity) {
        int[] variation = new int[rooms];
        // start from all 1, keep going till all food is allocated
        Arrays.fill(variation, 1);
        distributionsRecursive(food, rooms, roomCapacity, variation, rooms);
        return solutions.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int food = in.nextInt();
        int rooms = in.nextInt();
        int roomCapacity = in.nextInt();

        int total = possibleDistributions(food, rooms, roomCapacity);
        System.out.println(total);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to compute the result for k rooms from the result for k - 1 rooms.

I've simplified the problem a bit in allowing to store 0 tonnes in a room. If we have to store at least 1 we can just subtract this in advance and reduce the capacity of rooms by 1.

So we define a function calc: (Int,Int) => List[Int] that computes for a number of rooms and a capacity a list of numbers of combinations. The first entry contains the number of combinations we get for storing 0 , the next entry when storing 1 and so on.

We can easily compute this function for one room. So calc(1,m) gives us a list of ones up to the mth element and then it only contains zeros.

For a larger k we can define this function recursively. We just calculate calc(k - 1, m) and then build the new list by summing up prefixes of the old list. E.g. if we want to store 5 tons, we can store all 5 in the first room and 0 in the following rooms, or 4 in the first and 1 in the following and so on. So we have to sum up the combinations for 0 to 5 for the rest of the rooms.

As we have a maximal capacity we might have to leave out some of the combinations, i.e. if the room only has capacity 3 we must not count the combinations for storing 0 and 1 tons in the rest of the rooms.

I've implemented this approach in Scala. I've used streams (i.e. infinite Lists) but as you know the maximal amount of elements you need this is not necessary.

The time complexity of the approach should be O(k*n^2)

```
def calc(rooms: Int, capacity: Int): Stream[Long] =
  if(rooms == 1) {
    Stream.from(0).map(x => if(x <= capacity) 1L else 0L)
  } else {
    val rest = calc(rooms - 1, capacity)
    Stream.from(0).map(x => rest.take(x+1).drop(Math.max(0,x - capacity)).sum)
  }
```

You can try it here:

http://goo.gl/tVgflI

(I've replaced the Long by BigInt there to make it work for larger numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your recursion tree will become large if you do this in a naive manner. Let's say you have 10 tonnes and 3 rooms, and M=2. One valid arrangement is [2,3,5]. But you also have [2,5,3], [3,2,5], [3,5,2], [5,2,3], and [5,3,2]. So for every valid grouping of numbers, there are actually K! permutations.

A possibly better way to approach this problem would be to determine how many ways you can make K numbers (minimum M and maximum N) add up to N. Start by making the first number as large as possible, which would be `N-(M*(K-1))`. In my example, that would be:

```
10 - 2*(3-1) = 6
```

Giving the answer [6,2,2].

You can then build an algorithm to adjust the numbers to come up with valid combinations by "moving" values from left to right. In my example, you'd have:

```
6,2,2
5,3,2
4,4,2
4,3,3
```

You avoid the seemingly infinite recursion by ensuring that values are decreasing from left to right. For example, in the above you'd never have [3,4,3].

If you really want *all* valid arrangements, you can generate the permutations for each of the above combinations. I suspect that's not necessary, though.

I think that should be enough to get you started towards a good solution.

Comment: the problem is slightly different, though. a room cannot have more food than it's capacity M, and it must have at least 1. So in your example M can't be 2, because there will be no solution. I tried to use your suggestion, but I can't seem to make it work. For example, if `N=10`, `K=5`, `M=5`, the initial setup would be `[5,2,1,1,1]`. However, shifting values from left to right doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Stefan: I misunderstood. For some reason I thought M was the minimum. Blame it on lack of sleep. Or inattention. Glad you got a solution.

Answer (score 1):

First tip, remove `distributionsRecursive` and don't build up a list of solutions.  The list of all solutions is a huge data set.  Just produce a count.

That will let you turn `possibleDistributions` into a recursive function defined in terms of itself.  The recursive step will be, `possibleDistributions(food, rooms, roomCapacity) = sum from i = 1 to roomCapacity of possibleDistributions(food - i, rooms - 1, roomCapacity)`.

You will save a lot of memory, but still have your underlying performance problem.  However with a pure recursive function you can now fix that with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization.